# Skrollr on smaller screens - jQuery change multiple unknown props

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) to animate an svg.  I'm animating something growing down a page.  The code is comprised of hundreds of paths that look like this:

```
<path data-100="stroke-dashoffset:-129;" data-400="stroke-dashoffset:0;" id="v3" fill="none" stroke="#EEB853" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
M561.922,268.727c21,20.96,35-21.5,58-14.475c17.5,4.475,34.836,27.435,36.836,35.435" style="stroke-dasharray:6000;" />
```

Just to simplify that you can think of it like this:

```
data-100="stroke-dashoffset:-129;" data-400="stroke-dashoffset:0;"
```

The number after data- being the number of pixels down the user scrolls to set the style. Because different screens are different heights I was going to:

- Check screen height
- Loop through all the paths
- Take away some of the pixels of the data-**number** depending on height

So on a smaller screen you might end up with

```
data-50="stroke-dashoffset:-129;" data-350="stroke-dashoffset:0;"
```

[Is this link the best way to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984686/jquery-get-attributes) Does anyone have any other advice on achieving this?

Comment: Can't you use constants (https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#working-with-constants)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @prinzhorn pointed out, I managed it simply by doing the following:

```
var OFFSET = ($(window).height / 5);

$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#timeline").length > 0){
        var s = skrollr.init({
            constants: {
                screen_offset   :   OFFSET
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And then:

```
<path data-_screen_offset-100="stroke-dashoffset:-5772;" data-_screen_offset-5300="stroke-dashoffset:0;"/>
```

Remember to **remove** the underscore in the object that is passed to skrollr.

Comment: thanks for keeping so on top of all the skrollr stack overflow stuff.